# Edit CSS3 animation with jQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, css

is it possible to edit an animation like this

```
@-webkit-keyframes rotation {
  0%   { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  85% { -webkit-transform: rotate(1442deg); }
  94% { -webkit-transform: rotate(1438deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(1440deg); }
}
```

using JavaScript?

Thank you in advance,

Matteo

Comment: Since you can inject some CSS using javascript there is no reason you cant "edit" css.

Comment: Have you tried the standard syntax ? http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: Something like $('@-webkit-keyframes rotation').css('100%', '{ -webkit-transform: rotate(1440deg); }'); ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way should be the jQueryKeyframes plugin:
https://github.com/jQueryKeyframes/jQuery.Keyframes

It provides you with an simple syntax, so your example should look something like this:

```
$.keyframe.define([{
    name: 'rotation',
    0%   { 'transform': 'rotate(0deg)' },
    85% { 'transform': 'rotate(1442deg)' },
    94% { 'transform': 'rotate(1438deg)' },
    100% { 'transform': 'rotate(1440deg)' }
}]);
```

Manual ways of injecting CSS via JS should also work.